# scrapy: "sel" shortcut is deprecated.

Tags: python, scrapy

When I use Scrapy sel

```
scrapy shell "https://tw.yahoo.com/"
sel.xpath("//div[@id='news']").extract()
```

it will output the result(the picture below) but It said:
ScrapyDeprecationWarning: "sel" shortcut is deprecated. Use "response.xpath()", "response.css()" or "response.selector" instead

Is it an error ? How can I fix it?
Please teach me,THX

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xpath()` and `css()` method have been moved to `response`, so you can call them like this:

```
response.xpath("//div[@id='news']")
response.css("div#news")
```